# can jsf/primefaces application be hosted out of AWS

Tags: mysql, jsf-2, primefaces, amazon-web-services, tomcat6

Is it possible to use AWS services to host an application build in following technologies

1. jsf2/primefaces3
2. tomcat 6
3. mysql 5

Apart from these I need email services, blog etc a conventional java based package is this possible in AWS.

Presently I am using one of the hosting provider and my domain is also registered with them so how can I point the domain to point to the AWS hosted website. Is this possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer most of your questions. Yes it's possible to host an app with those technologies on AWS. You can host any application on an AWS server, as it's just like any other server but you must configure everything yourself, unless you are using a customized AMI.

I wouldn't recommend using AWS to send out email however, as in my experience, a lot of spammers have abused the AWS system, so if you are sending out email newsletters/etc... from an AWS server, it may be treated more strictly by other email server spam filters. It's best to use a third party solution for sending out bulk email.

As for your last question: "how can I point the domain to point to the AWS hosted website", that is way too complicated to answer here. I would suggest hiring someone experienced with DNS to manage this transition. I would recommend that you move your DNS hosting to Amazon's S3 routing service. Then you can easily manage your DNS and other AWS services from one console.

Good luck